# Android, Random created list content opening a new activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

Good day, i have a question about android that my teacher couldn't answer and i couldn't really find an answer.

Example Program: Shopping List

I Want to create a program where i can press a button and create a new list with whatever name i choose, for example List A then i press it again, List B and so on, until that point it's quite easy, my doubt is how can i create with that push of a button a new List that opens an activity with that given name with a specific template, for example i press List A and it opens an activity for List A with the same template for List B but without the content the data being shared by lists or me having to create the list manualy on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use extras for that.
From the activity where you are in the beginning you create a new Intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NameOfFirstActivity.this, NameOfListActivity.class);
```

Then you can put an extra to that intent:

```
intent.putExtra("listname", "ListA");
```

After that you start the activity:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

On the second activity you can get the extra you put in by calling this:

```
String listname = getIntent().getStringExtra("listname");
```

Then you can check what the listname is and then display different data for list A and list B.

Note: When you put an extra and when you get it you have to use the same String as the name. In this case the extra name is "listname" but you can use everything else too.

Comment: What do you want to show in the second activity? A list with items of the selected list (a or b or whatever)?

Comment: Basicaly the program consists in a first activity that has a list and a button that permites the user to add a new List, he can create has many lists has he wants, and when he presses any of the lists he created that opens a second activity (with an iqual template for all the other lists) but that has the items specific to that list

Comment: what you said previously helps, with passing data from one activity to another, but it requires me to manualy create that list on the database and the program itself, but if i use an ID i can probably make it more user dependable, it doesn't really help with making a template for all the lists be iqual but not inhereting the same data, i'm kind of new to android, so my knowledge is still limited, and what we learned in school didn't really help me solving that problem, tryed asking my teachers but they were clueless

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with template. Will the lists only contain strings?